# Ionic 5 ion-menu not animating properly when side is changed dynamically

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic5

When dynamically changing the side attribute of ion-menu the menu doesn't change the animation direction it only remembers the the initial animation direction.

example: the menu first renders with side="end" and works normally, then when changed on a click to side="start" the menu opens from the end position while animating to the start position.

the menu should open/animate from the specified side.

Comment: did you find any solution ?

Comment: Unfortunately no